# ORA-04088 and ORA-06512

Tags: sql, oracle10g

When using this trigger code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Verify_deathDate 
BEFORE INSERT Or UPDATE of deathDate, birthDate on Actor 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
IF (:NEW.deathDate < :NEW.birthDate) THEN 
    Raise_application_error(-20000, 'birthDate should be before deathDate'); 
END IF; 
END; 
/
```

and then this update query:

```
UPDATE Actor SET deathDate = '28-Dec-1937' , birthDate = '29-Dec-1938' 
WHERE actorID = '00069';
```

I get the following codes (only one is right):

```
ORA-20000: birthDate should be before deathDate
ORA-06512: at "OPS$U0853885.CHECK_DEATHDATE", line 3
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'OPS$xxxxxxxx.CHECK_DEATHDATE'
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, are you saying you don't want the error you're raising?

Comment: I dont want the last 2 errors(ORA-06512,ORA-06512). surely these are saying my trigger isnt correct?

Comment: What you get is a stack trace showing the "path" of the error that you've raised. In a way, it's just additional information about why and where your error `-20000` was created. Think about this way. Without the stack trace, you wouldn't even know which trigger created the error, should you re-use the same code elsewhere... You can find some additional info here: http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=318

Answer (score 4):

[Oracle recommends](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/triggers.htm) that you use triggers to constrain data only where you can't use (among other things) CHECK constraints. Since this is actually *simpler* to do, you should probably use that in this case;

```
CREATE TABLE Actor (
  id int, 
  name varchar(32), 
  birthdate date, 
  deathdate date, 
  CONSTRAINT birth_death CHECK (deathdate > birthdate)
);
```

This will enforce your business rule without an extra trigger.

Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/14f73/1).

Comment: An additional advantage of this approach over a trigger is that this constraint can be formally used for query transformations by the CBO.